# Take OrderedDictionary as an argument and apply random.gauss(mean,std)

Tags: python

I am trying to take a OrderedDict as an argument, then apply "random.gauss()" to the mean and standard deviation of the OrderedDict. My code is beneath.

```
def randomscores():
    items=OrderedD(csv_reader().items()) 
    return(lambda items: (random.gauss((int(items[1][1])),(int(items[1][2])))))
```

Here is one of the OrderedDicts I will use as an argument:

```
("B", [100, 10])
```

I wish for this to then print out another OrderedDict containing the name "b" and the result from the `random.gauss(100, 10)`.

Comment: This perfectly valid question was deleted while I was trying to answer it. I'll post the answer anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> import random

>>> items = OrderedDict((('B', [100, 10]), ('S', [8,80])))
>>> rs = OrderedDict((k, random.gauss(*v)) for k,v in items.items())
>>> rs
```

produces

```
OrderedDict([('B', 85.68779888033738), ('S', 56.80461868495082)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import random

od = OrderedDict()

def randomscores(items):
    for i in items:
        yield i, random.gauss(items[i][0],items[i][1])

od.update(randomscores(OrderedDict({'B':[100, 10], 'S':[8,80]})))
# OrderedDict([('S', 55.44697277296089), ('B', 82.56818034706545)])
```

Comment: the OP says the desired output is another OrderedDict, with the same keys